# Block iOS device

Tags: ios, mdm, profiles

My goal is to block a device under some circumstances and for predefined devices.

I am aware of the LockDevice feature of MDM. I am also aware of the "enforce to set a passcode" feature of MDM.
But is there a way to lock a device with a **predefined** passcode? (i.e. the passcode is not set, and I want to enforce the user to enter my passcode to use his device)

EDIT: As people said here, MDM makes use of a predefined user's passcode.
It there a workaround for this? Or maybe some other way of achieving my initial goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MDM command of configuration profile to do that. Password is always defined by an user.

Comment: Any workaround you can think of for accomplishing this goal (prevent user from using the device)?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? I assume that user should be able to do something. You can put device into a kiosk mode with an empty app to prevent user doing anything. However, kiosk mode works only on supervised devices.

Comment: This is some sort of an app among employees of a security company. My goal is to be able to block predefined employees from this app based on some logic conditions. What is kiosk mode and can it help me?

Comment: @AnatolyAnatoly Can you just wipe their device? Kiosk mode is the mode when you are locked inside of one app and you can't exit it (pressing home button does nothing and device will start this app after reset). Here is configuration profile to do that - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW35

Comment: Nope, wiping is no good. I need to be able to block and unblock a device remotely from another phone. This should be done from an app that is installed on both mine and their phones. As I press "block" button on this app, another phone is blocked and cannot be used. If I press "Unblock" it is unblocked. The most closest solution I found is the MDM's Kiosk mode and specify this app's bundle identifier. Will it fit my needs? Also, should I first set the devices to supervised mode using Apple Configurator, i.e. I need to have those device physically?

Comment: You will need to set them supervised, because only supervised devices can be put into kiosk mode. If you use Apple Configurator you will need to have them physically to set Supervise mode. There is also Enterprise Enrollment or Deployment Program. However, it's for enterprises which buy these devices in bulk. Your app will communicate with MDM server and let know that another device should be blocked and MDM server will set/remove Kiosk mode.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the only way to set a device in a Supervise mode is through the Apple Configurator?

Comment: Two ways - Apple Configurator or Apple device enrollment program(https://www.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/DEP_Business_Guide_EN_Feb14.pdf)